# Scrapy: Scraping very select URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape yahoo stocks for a school project, but I have no idea how to go through each link of a page with a very certain link. The goal is to iterate through each stock with a certain ending portion of the url like so:

```
Starting URL = ["https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=BMO.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m"]
```

The next URL would be something like:

```
#Canadian Imperial(note the "CM"):
"https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=CM.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m"

#Blackberry (note the "BB"):
"https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=BB.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m"
```

etc...

In other words, the only thing that would change would be the characters between **"hp?s="** and **".TO&a"**.

Wondering if this is possible or not. The ending portion of the URL must stay the same as that is the page I need to get to. Unfortuantely, there is no links within each page on yahoo to go to other stocks.

If I could do this with **Scrapy's Rules and SmglLinkExtractor**, that would be preferable.

Would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

## Current Scrapy code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from dirbot.items import Website
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["ca.finance.yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=BMO.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m"
    ]



    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"/q/hp\?s=\w+\.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m"), follow=True)
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        
        item = Website()
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/h2/text()').extract()

        print item['name']
```

Comment: Look into the .format() built-in

Comment: I would create a list if the characters you want to place in the middle of those two sections. Iterate over the list and pass the iterated item to the format().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a rule to `follow` the links matching the pattern:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"/q/hp\?s=\w+\.\w+&a=\d+&b=\d+&c=\d+&d=\d+&e=\d+&f=\d+&g=m"), follow=True)
]
```

Though, I am not sure that you need to check for all URL parameters here. Simplified version:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"/q/hp\?s=\w+\.\w+"), follow=True)
]
```

And, don't forget the imports:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
```

Comment: Interesting, and this will give me the url ending in 'TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m" every time? These values are very important, as they hold the information I need from every stock

Comment: rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"/q/hp\?s=\w+\.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m"), follow=True)
]

Comment: @McLean25 yup, looks good too. Whatever works for you. But you've got the idea.

Comment: hmm... so I tried all three of these 'allow' codes and none of them seemed to work... it only scrapes the start_url. And yes, I did remember the imports

Comment: Do there have to be links matching this description on the page in order for it to work?

Comment: @McLean25 for starters, you need to use `CrawlSpider` instead of a regular `Spider`.

Comment: @McLean25 also, in the starting url you are defining there are no links matching the `/q/hp\?s=\w+\.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m` expression except the `BMO.TO...` - it is extracting no links and doesn't follow anything.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. I didn't know that's how linkExtractor worked until a few minutes ago and now it makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your helps anyways much appreciated. Will use for future projects

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what I was talking about in the comments i left.

```
import urllib
import os

company_symbol = ["ACGL", "AFSI", "AGII", "AGNC", "ANAT", "ARCP", "ASBC", "ASPS", "BANF", "BBCN", "BGCP", "BNCL", "BOKF", "BPOP", "BRKL", "CACC", "CATY", "CBOE", "CBSH", "CFFN", "CHFC", "CINF", "CME ", "COLB", "CVBF", "ERIE", "ESGR", "ETFC", "EWBC", "EZPW", "FCFS", "FCNC", "FFBC", "FFIN", "FITB", "FMBI", "FMER", "FNFG", "FNGN", "FSRV", "FULT", "GBCI", "GLPI", "GLRE", "HBAN", "HBHC", "HLSS", "HOMB", "IBKC", "IBKR", "IBOC", "IPCC", "ISBC", "KRNY", "LPLA", "MBFI", "MHLD", "MKTX", "MTGE", "NAVG", "NBTB", "NDAQ", "NFBK", "NPBC", "NTRS", "NWBI", "ORIT", "OZRK", "PACW", "PBCT", "PCH ", "PNFP", "PRAA", "PVTB", "ROIC", "SAFT", "SBNY", "SBRA", "SCBT", "SEIC", "SIGI", "SIVB", "SLM ", "STFC", "SUSQ", "TCBI", "TFSL", "TRMK", "TROW", "UBSI", "UMBF", "UMPQ", "VRTS", "WABC", "WAFD", "WETF", "WRLD", "WTFC", "Z", "ZION"]

for company in company_symbol:
    url = 'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q={0}:{1}'.format(company, 'NASDAQ')
    nasdaq = urllib.urlopen(url)
    text = nasdaq.read()
    filename = 'nasdaq.txt'.format(company)
    with file(filename, 'a') as output:
        output.write(str(text))
```

This code will was written as an example of one way to change urls and do something with each url.

Comment: Hmmm, this could work, however I am looking for something that uses Scrapy Rules so that I don't have to create a list of every possible stock.

Comment: As it turns out, I will have to use this method. Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to scrape only predefined quotes for given period, then the logic is following:

1. Prepare the list of quotes you interested in e.g. ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'LOL', ...].
2. Use basic [scrapy.Spider](http://www.tsx.com/listings/listing-with-us/listed-company-directory).
3. Define [start_requests()](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) method and yield a sequence of requests from it.

Sample implementation:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "quotes"
    allowed_domains = ["ca.finance.yahoo.com"]
    quotes = ["BMO", "CM", "BB"]
    url_template = "https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%s.TO\
        &a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m"

    def start_requests(self):
        for quote in self.quotes:
            url = self.url_template % quote
            yield Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        # process
```

But if you need to get ALL TSX quotes data, then I would recommend you to scrape them from [available listings](http://www.tsx.com/listings/listing-with-us/listed-company-directory) and then use as in above example. Crawling the entire ca.finance.yahoo.com is obviously a bad idea.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Except I used the .format function . Thanks for your response anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of stocks you want to load the yahoo page for, you can get a list of the yahoo urls like this:

```
url_template = "https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s={}.TO&a=02&b=2&c=2005&d=02&e=2&f=2015&g=m"

stocks = ['CM', 'BB']
urls = [url_template.format(stock) for stock in stocks]
```

I haven't used scrapy, though, so I'm not sure if this is what you need.